# Where and Like query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

take below, using Query Builder Class:

```
public function search($saq)
{
    $array=$this->db
         ->select()
         ->order_by('id', 'DESC')       
         ->where("name Like '$saq%'")                    
         ->get('products');
    return $array->result();
}
```

Would this give a correct CodeIgniter query ?

Comment: your question is not clear please explain what is the problem and what is your expected output

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter's query builder has a function like() you can use, using your example:

```
public function search($saq) {
  $query=$this->db
         ->select()
         ->order_by('id', 'DESC')       
         ->like('name', $saq, 'after')                    
         ->get('products');
  return $query->result();
}
```

more information [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)